# How do I break on all functions that matches a pattern?

Tags: gdb

I'm trying to break on all pthread functions, but it looks like gdb doesn't support wildcard here:

```
(gdb) b pthread_*
Function "pthread_*" not defined.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `rbreak ^pthread_`

From [GDB: Setting Breakpoints](https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Breaks.html):

> rbreak regex
>
> > Set breakpoints on all functions matching the regular expression regex.
> >
> > The syntax of the regular expression is the standard one used with tools like grep. Note that this is different from the syntax used by shells, so for instance foo* matches all functions that include an fo followed by zero or more os. There is an implicit .* leading and trailing the regular expression you supply, so to match only functions that begin with foo, use ^foo.

Comment: Its really useful for debugging the C++ programs where we want to put the breakpoints for all member functions.... thanks for this information.

Comment: `.*` is not needed here, sub matches are the default.